# Semantic ui react Popup getting closed on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react's Popup element. Following is the my component's behaviour:

Hover -> Shows `text 1` (saved as a state variable)
Click -> Closes the hover text (attached an onClick which changes the value of state variable from `text 1` to `text 2`

Now apparently, on click the popup closes so I'm not able to see the hovered `text 2`.

Is there a way, to keep the popup text from closing. I've tried `e.stopPropogation()` in the `onClick` but it didn't work.

Comment: can you provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The popup has a props called `open` that takes the boolean.
This will help you,

```
<Popup
  content="Hello"
  open={true}
  trigger={<Button content="A trigger" />}
/>
```

you can pass the value to it by managing via state.
Here is the working example: [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/61lqw?file=/example.js)

Comment: Looks great. Can wrap this under an HOC and accordingly handle behaviour using `Open`